# Setup Mapcache (ms4w package) with FastCGI on IIS

Tags: mapserver, iis, mapcache

When I try starting MapCache using the IIS FastCGI module, I get an `Internal Server Error`

> .. mapcache.fcgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

I've already got MapServer running like this without any problems.

I'm using the MS4W v3.2.1 CGI binaries (includes compiled executables for FastCGI) and setting `MAPCACHE_CONFIG_FILE` in environment variables for FastCGI to the path of the xml configuration.

I wasn't able to find a good explanation of how to get this running. (Only things like "I got it running" - not very helpful)

I'm running Win10 with IIS10 and VC++2012 redistributable installed.